# How to specify accessibility attribute values for the menu item when using a custom view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, uiaccessibility

I am writing a custom `NSMenuItem` view that I would like to make accessible.  When I do not override `accessibilityIsIgnored` (so the `NSView` default of `YES` is returned), I see in Accessibility Inspector that there is a basic `AXMenuItem` object in the accessibility hierarchy for the menu item using the custom view, but it is missing most of the [required attributes for menu items](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Role.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007870-Roles-AXMenuItem) such as "Title":

[image: Screenshot of Accessibility Inspector locked on the AXMenuItem accessibility object, when ignoring accessibility]

The required attributes *are* set for menu items that do not use a custom view.

When I override `accessibilityIsIgnored` to return `NO`, then this results in an additional accessibility object being added to the hierarchy (by default an `AXUnknown` object):

[image: Screenshot of Accessibility Inspector locked on the AXUnknown accessibility object under the AXMenuItem object, when not ignoring accessibility]

Attribute values returned by an override of `accessibilityAttributeValue:` are applied to this `AXUnknown` object under the `AXMenuItem`, rather than the desired effect of being applied to the `AXMenuItem` object itself.

How do I supply the missing attribute values for the menu item?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm running into similar problems with the new Accessibility API in 10.10 as well.

Comment: Hi @FabianKreiser.  No, I was not able to find a solution.  I ended up filing rdar://18623851 on October 11, 2014.  So far I have not received feedback on this report, but I will post a follow-up here if I do.

Comment: Hello, is there any updates with regards to the above issue?